# Calculating COUNT of items on every user selection, how to make this faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, frontend, backend

I have a menu which is showing the number of items user can view, based on categories, so user can figure what is worth filtering further, very similar to:

https://www.next.co.uk/shop/gender-men

The problem is that having this count is consisting about 90% of the SQL query time. so instead of ~1 sec, every choice takes about 5 seconds of loading time, Since there's a query for every category.

I am trying to understand if there is a best practice to make it faster? Even on next is it kind of slow.

Comment: If you have a query that you want to make faster, you should include it *as text* (preferably formatted) in the question.

Comment: i don't necessarily ask about a query. the query is a simple count. just wonder if there's a better practice.

Comment: Also show us the schema (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`).